# TypeError: instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, eventemitter, emit

I'm trying to emit a event from child to parent component.

Parent:

parent.ts

```js
onChangeUpload(event){
  console.log('event');
  console.log(event);
}
```

```html
<app-upload (uploadEmit)="onChangeUpload($event)"></app-upload>
```

Child:

```js
@Output() uploadEmit: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

this.uploadEmit.emit('upload successful');
```

And i got this error:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: instance[output.propName].subscribe is not a function
```

```js
@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.6.2
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

Is this your import statement?

If it is, change it to

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

And disable VS Code auto-import. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not mentioned the Type, when we send data on event emit, we have to explicitly specify the type of data that we will be sending like:

**Child Component:**

```
<h3> Child Component </h3>
<button (click)="onSendData()">Send Data</button>
```

**Child Typescript:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Output() passData = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onSendData(){
    this.passData.emit("Hello From Child");
  }
}
```

You can checkout a working example [here](https://angular-ohfy84.stackblitz.io).

Comment: what is hello.component.html?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 it is the template file (in HTML) of the specific component, in this case `HelloComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem when I want to emit from child to parent. However, due to VS Code's auto import, it imported from event rather than angular/core. Firstly, disable auto import in VS Code.

Then, if your import is like this

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
```

Change it to

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```